# Unable to save screenshots

Tags: filesystem, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of a certain area using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> key combo, and after I take it and try to save it to any directory, I get a message:

```
Unable to capture screenshot

Error creating file. Please choose another location and retry
```

But no other location works either. I can save files fine in other contexts.

Comment: Which directory and filename are you using?

Comment: This doesn't even seem to be a valid question. No one would use crazy characters to save a screen shot in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was simply because I had invalid characters in the filename of the image, which the screenshot software does a poor job of conveying.

Comment: Invalid characters? There are no invalid characters in path names in Linux. What was the target file system?

Comment: @DavidFoerster It was my home directory. I had a '/' in the filename, and when removed, it saved fine. No changing of the target directory or anything like that. This is an invalid character.

Comment: Ok, that's some clarification. Though I wouldn't call the directory separator an “illegal” character. It just has a special meaning.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That's exactly why any invalid character is invalid

Comment: There's a difference between "this character carries a different syntactic meaning in that context" and "the syntax doesn't allow this character in that context".

Comment: Regardless it was not a valid character for the filename, for whatever reason